# How to get LocalDateTime stored as field in firestore in PojoObject?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I successcully stored LocalDateTime field in firestore but when i get these data back and map it to Pojo it shows serialization problem. Here is the error i get --

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Class java.time.LocalDateTime
> does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard,
> make sure these constructors are not stripped (found in field 'orderTime')

1. How do it solve it?
2. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

- If the framework **must** have a no-argument constructor, I think the java.time.LocalDateTime might not be what you really want because the class is decorated with final, which means you cannot extend the class with no-arg constructor on it.
- Another way you can try is importing the package org.joda.time with class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, the package extending more functionalities from java.time [joda.time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), hence it has the constructor with no arg.

Answer (score 1):

In a Pojo class, you need to define the default(no-argument), constructor. The error mention that you do not define a no-argument constructor.

Please refer to the below example.

```
public class User{

private String id;
private String name;

//Add this
public User(){
}

}
```

This will help to fix your error.

Comment: i have it already. Just one field of type LocalDateTime is creating problem